# Blender python script to translate the selected object to the snapped object within axes constraints

Tags: python, scripting

My desired behavior is the following. All edges are in X or Y or Z axes (Manhattan World) and I would like to find the closest edge from the selected line under the axis constraint (only move along y axis for this example).

[image]
[image]

From Blender documentation of bpy.ops.transform, I found the snap option.

```
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, False, False), mirror=False, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1.0, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False, snap=False, snap_target='CLOSEST', snap_point=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), snap_align=False, snap_normal=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), gpencil_strokes=False, cursor_transform=False, texture_space=False, remove_on_cancel=False, release_confirm=False, use_accurate=False, use_automerge_and_split=False)
```

Therefore, I tested following code but it moved exactly 300 along y axis only not snapped point.

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0,300,0), release_confirm=True, orient_matrix=((0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), snap=True, snap_target='CLOSEST', constraint_axis = (False, True, False))
```

Thanks for any helps!!

Comment: At the beginning you say you want to *"find"* closest edge, but later you use a transform operator, that **moves** an edge. So do you want to move an edge or only find another edge? Can you tell why do you need this (in case this is [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Hi! The figure above shows the home design. I would like to measure the width of the wall which is represented as two individual edges (two objects). If I could find the closest edge (the snapped one along the axis), the delta from the selected object to the snapped object is the width of the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script selects the nearest edge going in the same direction as the active edge:

```
import bpy, bmesh

me = bpy.context.active_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
edge = bm.select_history.active
vec1 = edge.verts[0].co - edge.verts[1].co
vec2 = vec1 * -1
center = edge.verts[0].co + vec2 * 0.5

smallest_distance = 999
closest_edge = None

for e in bm.edges:
    if e is edge:
        continue
    vec = e.verts[0].co - e.verts[1].co
    if vec != vec1 and vec != vec2:
        continue
    distance = (center - (e.verts[0].co - vec *.5)).length
    if distance < smallest_distance:
        smallest_distance = distance
        closest_edge = e

closest_edge.select_set(True)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! My apology for the late check.